# Why does my code run multiple times before I type data into the table? How do I make an action button that creates a table in the ui?

Tags: r, shiny

I am reading code from an excel sheet and generating a site with table so a user can input data. This data generates other figures based on under-lying vectors. However whenever I run it, it is extremely slow and runs multiple times. Normally having `rHandsontableOutput("tbl")` in the ui generates a table but not under the control of the action button. This is an I/O economic analysis tool.

I am not too familiar with how the arguments of `output$(something)` work. I have tried `observeEvent`, `eventReactive`. `Isolate()` might help me, but I am not sure on how to implement it. Everything else works, I just don't know how to make the action button work and make the code run more efficiently.

## Code:

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(matlib)
library(rhandsontable)
library(openxlsx) #used for writing data into excel xlsxFilfiles

states <- getStates()
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
                    actionButton("action","Generate"),
                    #renderRHandsontable("Stats"),
                    textOutput("helper")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(# tableOutput('table')
                    rHandsontableOutput("tbl")
                  )
                ))

server <- function(input, output){
  #does not work
  output$action <- reactive(input$action,output$tbl)
  #output$action <- reactive(input$action,rHandsontableOutput("tbl"))
  
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    output$tbl("Stats")
  })

  inputVals <- eventReactive(input$action, {runif(input$action)})

  df_new2 <- 0 
  
  #table I want to output
  output$tbl <- renderRHandsontable({
    
    df_new2 <<- comparison() #function that works
    rhandsontable(df_new2)
  })
}
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

## Error:

```
Error in $.shinyoutput(output, tbl) :  
  Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reproducible data, I'm not sure this will completely solve your problem. If it is your intent to delay the production of the table, then `eventReactive()` is a good way to do this. In the curly brackets, you can define what the output should be after the event. From there, you can render your table with the output.

Your event reactive script can be as lengthy as you need it to be, but the output should reflect what you want sent to the table rendering - similar to any reactive object. Fortunately, everything inside of the curly brackets will be on hold until the event is triggered.

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
mainPanel(# tableOutput('table')
  actionButton("action","Generate"),
  rHandsontableOutput("tbl")
))

server <- function(input, output){
  values <- eventReactive(input$action, {
    mtcars
  })

  #table I want to output
  output$tbl <- renderRHandsontable({

    rhandsontable(values())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!